# returning back to same page if validation fails in grails

Tags: grails, redirect

I am doing some form validation (using a plugin) in my controller and set a boolean variable called `status =true/false` if the validation passes/fails

this validation is happening in `update` action , and the request is coming from `edit.gsp`.
If the validation fails I want the control to go back to edit.gsp. can I achieve this or I have to create the `update.gsp` separately and copy the content of `edit.gsp` to show the edited form values with the errror message on update.gsp page?   I want avoid passing all other paramters to backend and back for just 1 fields sanitization check.

It should look something similar like javascript but actually backend validation redirecting to same page on error..
How do I achieve this?
On successful validation I am doing a redirect to `manageTemplate.gsp`.

Regards,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you trigger the validation using the plugin I would think the easiest way is to write a custom validator on your domain object. More info: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html

If you don't want to (or can't) go down that route you can manually check the validation against the plugin in your controller. It will basically be the same pattern that the scaffolded Grails pages/controllers use.

In your controller you can validate with your plugin and if the domain instance doesn't validate you redirect the User back to the edit action and include the 'params'. That way all the fields will still be populated as they were before.

A updated snippet from a scaffolded Grails controller (for a domain object called Tag):

```
    // ...
    // Code above here just gets the domain object to edit (tagInstance in this case)
    // and checks that the object hasn't be updated in the meantime

    tagInstance.properties = params

    // params have been applied to object, you can now do custom validation

    def status = extraValidationService.validate( tagInstance ) // or however you run the validation

    if ( !status ) {
       flash.message = "Did not pass custom validation"
       render(view: "edit", model: [tagInstance: tagInstance]) // Back to same edit page (field values maintained)
       return        
    }

    // Everything below here is unchanged

    if ( !tagInstance.save( flush: true, failOnError: false ) ) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [tagInstance: tagInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'tag.label', default: 'Tag'), tagInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: tagInstance.id) // This is where you redirect to the manageTemplate action.gsp
```

This will not give you the validation highlighting on the fields that failed validation. To get that you can either use the custom validator method or you may (I've never done it) be able to manually 'tell' a domain object which fields failed validation and why.